# Displaying logged in user in the Navigation Drawer using it's layout from a MainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences, navigation-drawer

I am looking for a solution as to how I can set the text of username and email in the navigation drawer from a MainActivity referencing the IDs within another layout.

```
nav_header_main.xml
```

[MainActivity Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrLMl.png)

[MainActivity Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAfeS.png)

Below is code displaying the logged in user  referencing the TextViews from the **activity_main.xml** however I need the "**R.id." to reference the username and email TextViews inside the nav_header_main.xml** to be able to display user's details in a navigation drawer header.

**MainActivity.java**

```
if(!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
        textviewUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
        textviewEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
     /*
        textviewUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewUsernameNav);
     textViewEmail= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewEmailNav); */

         textviewEmail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getEmail());
         textviewUsername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername());
```

**nav_header_xml**

```
android:id="@+id/nav_header_main_id"

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewUsernameNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEmailNav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="username@email.com" />
```

Comment: add navigation view layout and main activity xml

Comment: Try my answer to update the navigation headerview username and email TextView

Comment: The problem is It doesn't allow me to reference the TextViews inside of the nav_header_main.xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use `NavigationView.getHeaderView(0)` to get the header view.
2. Use `HeaderView.findViewById()` to get reference of child view.

**Try this:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    View mHeaderView;

    TextView textViewUsername;
    TextView textViewEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...................
        ..........................

        // NavigationView
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // NavigationView Header
        mHeaderView =  mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        // View
        textViewUsername = (TextView) mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsernameNav);
        textViewEmail= (TextView) mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmailNav);

        // Set username & email
        textViewUsername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername());
        textViewEmail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getEmail());


        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you sir! It worked! :D

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use findViewById on the header view, something like this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
textviewUsername= (TextView) headerView.findViewById((R.id.username));
```